# Data validation with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I currently galley with data validation via Hibernate. Especially with the @Pattern annotation

Wholesale verification is always false, no matter what I do, so I can not save the object.

I try this, among other things:

```
@NotNull
@Size(max=30)
@SafeHtml
@Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]", messsage="the name can only contain letters")
private String name;
```

et ceci :

```
@NotNull
@Size(max=30)
@SafeHtml
@Pattern(regexp="\\D", messsage="the name can only contain letters")
private String name;
```

In both case, if i write "toto," I have the error message that appears.

Someone an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `[a-zA-Z]*`

The patterns you have look like they only capture one letter.  You need a * or a + to suggest multiple letters.